# How to identify matching values in dictionary and create a new string with only those keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary, counter

I have a method that pulls repeating letters from a string and adds them to a dictionary with the amount of times they repeat as the values. Now what I would like to do is pull all the keys that have matching values and create a string with only those keys.

example:

```
text = "theerrrdd"
count = {}
same_value = ""

for ch in text:
    if text.count(ch) > 1:
        count[ch] = text.count(ch)
```

How can I check count for keys with matching values, and if found, add those keys to same_value?

So in this example "e" and "d" would both have a value of 2. I want to add them to same_value so that when called, same_value would return "ed".
I basically just want to be able to identify which letters repeated the same amount of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a letter to count mapping, then reverse this mapping. Using the `collections` module:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

text = 'theerrrdd'

# create dictionary mapping letter to count
letter_count = Counter(text)

# reverse mapping to give count to letters mapping
count_letters = defaultdict(list)
for letter, count in letter_count.items():
    count_letters[count].append(letter)
```

Result:

```
print(count_letters)

defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: ['t', 'h'],
                             2: ['e', 'd'],
                             3: ['r']})
```

Then, for example, `count_letters[2]` gives you all letters which are seen twice in your input string.

Using `str.count` in a loop is inefficient as it requires a full iteration of your string *for each letter*. In other words, such an algorithm has quadratic complexity, while `collections.Counter` has linear complexity.

Answer (score 0):

From `counter` dictionary, create another dictionary with all same count letters as values and the count as key. Iterate through values of this newly created dictionary to find all values whose length is greater than 1 and then form strings:

```
from collections import defaultdict

text = "theerrrdd"
count = {}

new_dict = defaultdict(list)

for ch in text:
    if text.count(ch) > 1:
        count[ch] = text.count(ch)    

for k, v in count.items():
    new_dict[v].append(k)

same_values_list = [v for v in new_dict.values() if len(v) > 1]

for x in same_values_list:
    print(''.join(x))
# ed
```

`new_dict` is the newly created dictionary with count as key and all letters with that count as the value for that key:

```
print(new_dict)

# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {2: ['e', 'd'],
#                              3: ['r']})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use `set()` to get just the unique characters in the string, loop through the set and create a dict where the counts are the keys with lists of characters for each count. Then you can generate strings for each count using `join()`.

```
text = "theerrrdd"
chars = set(text)
counts = {}

for ch in chars:
    ch_count = text.count(ch)
    if counts.get(ch_count, None):
        counts[ch_count].append(ch)
    else:
        counts[ch_count] = [ch]

# print string of chars where count is 2
print(''.join(counts[2]))
# OUTPUT
# ed
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most simple solution of all !!

```
from collections import Counter

text = "theerrrdd"
count = Counter(text)
same_value = ''.join([k for k in count.keys() if count[k] > 1])

print(count)
print(same_value)
```